# How do I say something is the superlative of a group in German?

Tags: grammar, comparison

What is the correct German way for the English construction involving identifying the superlative in a group? For instance

> Lake Michigan is the largest of the Great Lakes?

or

> It was the darkest of nights.

Is there a difference in how to write it if the group is definite (e.g., "the Great Lakes") versus indefinite (nights, books, games)? Would a genitive-style approach work, or is there another formulation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are subtle differences when using a superlative for an idiomatic group or when using it simply with plural. This can nicely be shown with the examples you gave.

#### Superlative and plural

> It was the darkest of nights. - *Es war die dunkelste aller Nächte.*

Note that we can use *"aller"* here to put emphasis on the fact that a variable number of many nights are judged here. Similar examples would be

> - *Fritz ist der beste aller Schüler [pl.].*
> - *Die schönste aller Blumen ist die Rose.*

We can of course replace *"aller"* (meaning the sum of all) by any other expression to precise the quantity:

> *Das dickste **der fünf** Bücher, die ich gelesen hatte war...*
> *Die hübscheste **meiner** Töchter ist die Susi.*
> *Das beste **Deiner** Programme ist...*

Only if the quantity is invariable we may also use the simple plural:

> *In diesem Strauß ist die schönste der Blumen eine Rose.*

This is however only rarely done as then using singular is preferred:

> *Die schönste Blume in diesem Strauß ist eine Rose.*
> *Fritz ist der beste Schüler [sing.].*

#### Superlative and a named group

> Lake Michigan is the largest of the Great Lakes.

In this case we are dealing with the fixed name *Great Lakes* where the quantity is invariable and thus we translate

> *Lake Michigan ist der größte der Großen Seen.*

Note the difference when we say

> *Lake Michigan ist der größte aller großen Seen.*

In the latter case the superlative relates not to the Great Lakes but to all great lakes in the world.

Comment: So is it preferred to say

«Lake Michigan ist der größte Große See»

instead of

«Lake Michigan ist der größte der Großen Seen»,

or are both acceptable? Is the second considered more literary rather than _Umgangsprache_?

Comment: The idiomatic usage is plural in German [Große Seen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Fe_Seen). Therefore I would not recommend to say *"der größte Große See"*. Note that it would be fine to say "*der größte See der großen Seen  Nordamerikas*" or simply *"der größte See in Nordamerika"*.

Comment: As with all genitives in German you will also hear "von" constructions: "Lake Michigan ist der größte von den Großen Seen." "Das dickste von den fünf Büchern..." "Die hübscheste von meinen Töchtern..." (but what kind of parent would make such a statement? :P )

Comment: @Elena: Wir wollen aber keine schlechte Sprache unterrichten, oder?

Comment: @Takkat: Wieso `aller` Nächte? Hörst Du ein `of all nights`?

Answer (score 2):

> Lake Michigan is the largest of the Great Lakes?

```
Der Michigan-See ist der größte der Großen Seen?
```

> It was the darkest of nights.

```
Es war die dunkelste der Nächte.
```

oder

```
Der Nächte war es die dunkelste.
```

Comment: "Der Nächte war dies die dunkelste." is not really good.

Comment: Beispiel 2 und 3 verwendet man aber eigentlich nur auf der Bühne.

Comment: Ich nicht. "Es war das teuerste der Essen." ist ganz normaler Sprachgebrauch - vielleicht nicht in Neukölln.

Comment: @user: "Es war das teuerste der Essen." könnte sich vielleicht in gewissen Situationen anbieten, aber meines Erachtens ist "Es war das teuerste Essen." meist natürlicher. "Der Essen war es das teuerste." ist definitiv nicht gängige gesprochene Sprache.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: In der Sprache ist überhaupt gar nichts natürlicher. Sprache ist per se Kultur, nicht Natur. Version 2 der Nachtsätze ist auch nur eine Alternative. Aus "Es war die dunkelste Nacht" ergibt sich aber kein Vergleich mit anderen Nächten, sondern mit anderen Stufen von Dunkelheit. Ich würde `It was the darkest night.` mit `Es war die dunkelste Nacht` übersetzen, aber mein Englisch ist nicht so toll - vielleicht ist `darkest of nights` etwas anderes, als ich denke.

Comment: @user: Ich kenne den Unterschied zwischen Kultur und Natur, aber in der Sprachkultur wird _natürlich_ durchaus im übertragenen Sinne gebraucht. Für mich ist "Es war die dunkelste Nacht" natürlich `:-)` ein Vergleich mit anderen Nächten, nur dass unspezifiziert bleibt, mit welchen Nächten verglichen wird. Bei "Es war das teuerste Essen" ist natürlich das teuerste auf der Speisekarte gemeint, wenn gerade von einem Restaurantbesuch gesprochen wird. (Ja, dieser Kommentar ist bewusst ein wenig provokant formuliert.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Du meinst Gewohnheit? Ja, es ist Deine Gewohnheit, andere haben andere Gewohnheiten. Aber was ist mit dem 'of' - was macht das 'of' im englischen Satz?

Comment: @blindfold: Pardon - meine frühere Antwort kam wohl nicht an. Sie lautete: Inwiefern?

Comment: @user: Klar, natürlich. Und ich meinte weiterhin: Die Mehrheit der Leute hat die Gewohnheit, "Es war das teuerste Essen" ohne "der" zu sagen (wenn sie denn so etwas sagen wollen), und nur sehr wenige werden die Gewohnheit haben, "Der Essen war es das teuerste" zu sagen. Betreffend "mein Englisch ist nicht so toll": Ich habe mal auf [english.se] gefragt, [was "the darkest of nights" bedeutet](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55073) - sehr interessante Antworten!

Comment: But you didn't raise the question, why not just using `it was the darkest night`, which sounds more common to me too, so if somebody decides to use an `of nights` - I guess this fine distinction should be made too, and not the most common, somehow fitting term be choosen. No answer on EL&U touches the `of`.

Comment: @user (found your comment just now): See the comments [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55073).

Comment: Bestärkt mich ja, der jüngste Kommentar: Eine besondere Gewichtung, die `Es war die schwärzeste der Nächte` im Gegensatz zu `Es war die schwärzeste Nacht` auch transportiert. Also gerade weil man den geläufigsten Ausdruck **nicht** benutzt, trifft man es.

Comment: @user (please don't forget `@Hendrik` if you want to notify me): Da ist in der Tat was dran. Wobei "darkest of nights" nach Google _viel_ geläufiger ist als "dunkelste der Nächte".

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Weil es eine prominente Zeile aus Harry Potter ist. Google ngram oder einfach wieviel Suchtreffer es gibt?

Comment: @user: Versuch's selbst. Das Ergebnis: Es liegt kaum an Harry Potter (auch wenn es in den letzten 10 Jahren einen klaren Aufwärtstrend gibt), und auf Deutsch gibt es keine Treffer.

Comment: @user: In Harry Potter kommt's anscheinend nicht vor - es sei denn, man lässt auch Fanfiction gelten.

Comment: I can't reconstruct how I searched yesterday, but multiple entries from page 1 contained the words "Harry Potter", so I thought it is a citation, maybe the beginning of a book.

Comment: @user (don't forget `@Hendrik` `:-)`): Yes, a search for "it was the darkest of nights" leads to a harry potter fanfiction (and this very page as the top result ...).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not really a difference between definite and indefinite:

e.g. "it was the darkest of nights"

"Dies war die dunkelste der Nächte." (edit: actually this would be: "Dies war die dunkelste Nacht")

and limited to only "summer nights" would be:
"Dies war die dunkelste der Sommernächte." (edit: actually this would be: "Dies war die dunkelste Sommernacht")